# Click on Checkbox in Website using Excel VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

There is a website that has some data I want for my work. I login check some checkbox and submit, then the website will send me an email with my data. But it takes way too long to receive my information so I want to automate it so everyday first hour in the morning the information is requested, like that I will already have it on my email when I need it.

I modified some code and I already managed to login and go to the page where I need to click the checkbox (there are three of them) and then click on a submit button.

```
Sub GetTable()

Dim ieApp As InternetExplorer
Dim ieDoc As Object
Dim ieTable As Object
Dim chkBox As Object

'create a new instance of ie
Set ieApp = New InternetExplorer

'you don’t need this, but it’s good for debugging
ieApp.Visible = True

'assume we’re not logged in and just go directly to the login page
ieApp.Navigate "http://mydata/aspx/mydataLogon.aspx?Language=2"
Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

Set ieDoc = ieApp.Document

'fill in the login form – View Source from your browser to get the control names
With ieDoc.forms(0)
    .txtUsername.Value = "usertest"
    .txtPassword.Value = "test123"
    .Submit
End With
Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

'now that we’re in, go to the page we want
ieApp.Navigate "http://mydata/InventoryTracking/aspx/rptDefault.aspx?rpt=../aspx/invRptDetailReport.aspx"

Set ieDoc = ieApp.Document

With ieDoc

    'I tried with getElementbyId, I dont get any error but the chkbox still comes as with a nothing value
    Set chkBox = ieDoc.getElementByid("cblPlants_0")

    'therefore these give error too, I dont know why. A an object variable or with block variable not set error
    chkBox.Click
    chkBox.Checked = True

    'here I get an object variable or with block variable not set error
    ieDoc.getElementByid("cblPlants_0").Click

    .Submit
End With

End sub
```

The checkbox control I want is inside of this:

```
'first there is a form and this is how the iframe is first called I think
<form name="_ctl1" method="post" action="rptDefault.aspx" id="_ctl1">
    <table width="100%" HEIGHT="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">  
        <TR>
            <TD CLASS="Normal" COLSPAN="4"><IFRAME ID="IFRAME1" NAME="IFRAME1" SRC="../aspx/invRptDetailReport.aspx" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%"></IFRAME></TD>
        </TR>  

'Now the iframe1 goes like this

<form name="frmRptDetailReport" method="POST" action="invRptDetailReport.aspx" id="frmRptDetailReport">  
    <table id="htblMainBody" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" bgcolor="#E5DBE2">  

        <tr><td <a id="lbtnSelect" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;lbtnSelect&#39;,&#39;&#39;)"</a>  
        <div id="divChkboxlist" class="scrollingControlContainer scrollingCheckBoxList" onscroll="saveScrollPos();">  
             <table id="cblPlants" border="0" style="font-family:Arial;font-size:11px;width:275px;overflow: scroll"><tr>  
                    <tr><td><input id="cblPlants_0" type="checkbox" name="cblPlants:0" onclick="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;cblPlants$0\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" language="javascript" /><label for="cblPlants_0">1X1 -Confecciones</label></td>
    </tr>
```

How can I check this check box on this page? After the checkbox is checked I will receive the email I want.

If you need more information please tell me

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ieDoc.querySelector("#cblPlants_0").click
```

Equivalent to:

```
ieDoc.getElementById("cblPlants_0").click
```

Remember to have proper page load waits after the .Navigate step before attempting the click

```
While ieApp.Busy Or ieApp.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

Set ieDoc = ieApp.Document

ieDoc.getElementById("cblPlants_0").click
```

You may need an additional wait before the click. Step through with F8 to test.

You could also try executing the javascript

```
ieDoc.parentWindow.execScript "javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'cblPlants$0\',\'\')', 0)"
```

Comment: Hi, queryselector gives "Object doesnt support this property or method". The getElementByID is still giving "Object variable or With block variable not set" . The execScript doesnt do anything, I am not seeing the checkbox checked on the website.

Comment: leaving the application.wait as you said. The querySelector still gives gives "Runtime error 438: Object doesnt support this property or method". The getElementbyID still gives the "Err 91 Object variable or with block variable not set"

Comment: that would imply the id isn't static or the element is nested within something else. Can you still see that id on the page and is it inside a parent iframe/frame tag?

Comment: The checkbox is inside the a "scrollingControlContainer" which is inside table inside a form like I specified above on my question. Or what do you mean? My experience of html is two days really heh

Comment: Does the form have a parent iframe/frame tag element? <iframe> or <frame>

Comment: depending on whether same origin policy is enforced... if it is you need to switch to selenium and Chrome/FireFox, if not try navigating to the src of the iframe first. I have done an edit to show this. Change the id for the frame if it is not _IFRAME1_  Keep the # at the start.

Comment: The `ieApp.Navigate2 ieApp.querySelector("#IFRAME1").src` is giving `Runtime Error 438: Object doesnt support this property or method`. Thinking it might be a type, I changed Navigate2 to Navigate and the same error persists.

Comment: Oops! add .document ieApp.Navigate2 ieApp.document.querySelector("#IFRAME1").src

Comment: Still gives the same error. Do you need more information? The page is a corporate website and I am trying not to share too much sensible information about it

Comment: ieApp.Navigate2 ieApp.document.querySelector("#IFRAME1").getAttribute("src")

Comment: or ieApp.Navigate2 ieApp.document.getElementById("IFRAME1").getAttribute("src")

Comment: `ieApp.Navigate2 ieApp.Document.getElementById("IFRAME1").getAttribute("src")` worked but it took me to a new page, to the `../aspx/invRptDetailReport.aspx` part of the `ieApp.Navigate "http://mydata/InventoryTracking/aspx/rptDefault.aspx?rpt=../aspx/invRptDetailReport.aspx"` I had before. Then the`ieDoc.getElementById("cblPlants_0").click` gives an "Object Required error"

Comment: Looks like your element is not inside the iframe. Is it actually after the iframe? The iframe end with </iframe> and there can be more than one. The form has to be between <iframe> and </iframe> to be inside the iframe.

Comment: I checked it again and i updated the html, I hope it does make it easier to understand

Comment: Hi @QHarr, was my edit good enough? Thanks for all the help you have given so far

Comment: what happened with executing the javascript?

Comment: The execScript didnt do anything, I am not seeing the checkbox checked on the website. My goal is to have 3 checkbox marked and then press another button to that will send me the email I need

Comment: try ieApp.document.parentWindow.execScript "document.getElementById('cblPlants_0').checked = true;"